# Reading SOAP response with PHP

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap-client

I am trying to read SOAP response with PHP but I got this error:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document in C:\xampp\htdocs\clinics\sedeeq.php on line 10

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): :complexType></xs:element></xs:choice></xs:complexType></xs:element></xs:schema> in C:\xampp\htdocs\clinics\sedeeq.php on line 10

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^ in C:\xampp\htdocs\clinics\sedeeq.php on line 10
```

And this is my PHP code:

```
$soap_client = new SoapClient("http://test.com/WebSrvOutApp/OutApp.asmx?WSDL");
        $data = $soap_client->OutGetOpdSchedule("test","test_2020");
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data->OutGetOpdScheduleResult->any);
```

Comment: Can you share the SOAP response ($data->OutGetOpdScheduleResult->any).

Comment: the response is on this file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gfVHr8j99kUaeShEg-uutTzayR410ZL6/view?usp=sharing